# Fechamento de arquivo

Tags: c#, .net, arquivo, dispose

Eu preciso deixar o arquivo livre, sem ficar em uso, pois está barrando. Segue o código:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
XmlTextWriter tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);

XmlSerializerNamespaces xsn = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xsn.Add("", "http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe");

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TNFe));
FileStream arquivo = new FileStream("C:\\" + chave_nfe + "-NFe.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);

ser.Serialize(arquivo, nfe, xsn);
```

Se eu faço:

```
sw.Close();
```

O arquivo ainda continua em uso, e não funciona como esperado. E se eu faço:

```
arquivo.Dispose();
```

Funciona, só que ele não monitora a pasta, não entendo o porque disso ocorrer, o código de monitoramento é logo em seguida:

```
 form = new FormProgressBar();
 form.Show();

 int X = 6000;
 form.MaximumBar(X);

 // Faço o laço para atualizar a barra
 for (int i = 0; i < X; i++)
 {
       // Método que atualiza a barra e o texto da barra
       form.AtualizaBarra("Aguarde...");
       // Insiro algum código que desejo e vou mostrando o status da atualização
 }

 // clsdb.ExecutaSQL("insert into nfe (n_nota, chave) values ('" + txtnumero.Text + "','" + digito(chave) + "')");
 messagebox = 0;
 messageboxxml = 0;

 #region MONITORAR PASTA

 //Dizemos agora se é para monitorar os subdiretórios ou não
 fsw.IncludeSubdirectories = false;

 //Através de um Enum dizemos quais eventos devem ser monitorados, modificação da data do arquivo, tamanho, etc...
 fsw.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

 //Dizemos quais tipos de arquivos devem ser monitorados, *.*, *.xml, *.txt, etc...
 //fsw.Filter = "*.xml";
 //fsw.Filter = "*.ERR";

 //Definimos agora os eventos a serem gerados
 fsw.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Created);
 fsw.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fsw_Changed);
 fsw.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(fsw_Error);

 // A propriedade abaixo define que a monitoração deve iniciar, se false, a pasta não será monitorada
 fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Esse é o código que fica tanto no evento `Created` ou `Changed`, ele não executa.

```
 FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);

 while (arquivoTravado(fileinfo))
 {
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
 }

 System.Xml.XmlDocument xmldoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

 xmldoc.Load(e.FullPath);

 if (e.FullPath.Length == 97)
 {
     System.Xml.XmlNode DadosLote = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("DadosLoteNfe");
     System.Xml.XmlNode NumeroLote = DadosLote.SelectSingleNode("NumeroLoteGerado");

     string nlote = NumeroLote.InnerText;
     clsdb.ExecutaSQL("update nfe set num_lote = '" + nlote + "' where n_nota = '" + txtnumero.Text + "'");
  }
```

Como posso fazer, para que o arquivo fique livre para ser tratado, e que o monitoramento continue funcionando?

Comment: você já tentou usando um bloco `using` ?

Comment: Não, vou tentar. Obrigado.

Comment: Preste atenção na forma que o código deve ser colocado na pergunta para as próximas vezes. Não crie snippets de código para c#, por exemplo.

Comment: Desculpe-me pelo engano.

Comment: está usando o `FileSystemWatcher` correto ? acredito que esteja usando de forma errada. 

Se o arquivo ainda não foi fechado, ele deve estar disparando o evento `fsw_Changed` e aparenta estar funcionando pra você. 
Se você fecha o arquivo, ele não irá disparar o evento `fsw_Created` porque o arquivo foi criado antes do evento ser associado ao `fsw`.  Seria bom se colocasse o código completo e sem essas quebras para que possa entender o que realmente está fazendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve abrir os recursos deforma que ele se fechem sozinho, algo assim:

```
using (var sw = new StringWriter())
using (var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
using (var arquivo = new FileStream("C:\\" + chave_nfe + "-NFe.xml", FileMode.CreateNew) {
    // ... faz o que deve aqui
}
```

Em C# 8 já pode fazer:

```
using var sw = new StringWriter());
using var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw));
using var arquivo = new FileStream("C:\\" + chave_nfe + "-NFe.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
// ... faz o que deve aqui
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/UsingTry.cs).

Tem erros no uso do formulário no acesso ao banco de dados (se tirar o comentário), mas são outros problemas, ficaria amplo demais responder isso, faça novas perguntas.

O problema do não monitoramento pode estar relacionado ao fato de não ter o arquivo fechado, se não for é um outro problema também, e precisaríamos de mais informações em nova pergunta para ajudar adequadamente, teria que ver como est´pa criando o monitoramento, o que está ocorrendo, como testou, etc.

Comment: O problema, que quando não uso o close ou dispose, o monitoramento funciona, ele só não funciona quando utilizo. Vou fazer o teste com o using, pra ver se funciona conforme o esperado.

Comment: Funciona por coincidência, porque não é o jeito correto. Primeiro precisa fazer o uso correto do arquivo e depois ver porque não funciona o monitoramento quando o resto está certo. Mas quando for perguntar sobre isso, certifique-se de colocar todas informações que possam ajudar as pessoas te ajudarem.

Comment: Tentei da forma que me auxiliou, o using, funciona, gera o arquivo e o libera, porém a pasta não está sendo monitorada, vou atualizar a pergunta com o código de monitoramento.

Comment: Desculpe pelo engano, funcionou sim, só mudei o monitoramento de lugar no código, porque fiz o debug e não estava entrando nele, então foi só mudar, e ficou do jeito que eu precisava, muito obrigado pela ajuda.